# Is this Swift if statement syntax written correctly?

Tags: swiftui

I am using Xcode to make an app that has many buttons inside a ForEach loop inside a LazyVGrid. I added an `if else` statement to my code to make one of the buttons have a different font size, but it is causing Xcode to take a very long time to build the program and causing SourceKitService to take up large amounts of CPU. It was running well before I added the if else statement and I am unsure why it is taking so long to build now.

It is also giving me this error message: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

This is my code: (it is inside a struct)

```
 var text: String
 let columns = [
GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0),
GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0),
GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0),
GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0),
GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0),
GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0)]
let numbers = ["+", "-", "x", "÷", "=", "Carry", "(", ")", "%", "<", ">", "Borrow", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", ",", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "."] 
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                Button(action: {
                    text += number
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                    Rectangle()
                            .frame(width: g.size.width/6, height: g.size.height/2)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .border(.gray, width: 1)
                        Text(number)
                        if (number = "Carry") {
                            .font(.system(size: g.size.width/40))
                        } else {
                            .font(.system(size: g.size.width/20))
                        }
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            }
        }
```

Comment: [ternary](https://medium.com/@nlinh142/ternary-conditional-operator-in-swift-what-usage-6bb9fea039ce) is probably better. But I would use sporadically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you probably want the double equals sign to test equality, rather than the single equals for assignment (i.e., `number == "Carry"`).

Also, using if-else statements around modifiers isn't great (I'm surprised it works at all, to be honest). Instead, you should limit the conditionals to the arguments you pass in. For example:

```swift
Text(number)
  .font(
    .system(
      size: number == "Carry" ? g.size.width / 40 : g.size.width / 20
    )
  )
```

Comment: `g.size.width / (number == "Carry" ? 40 : 20)`